# Can't hit API endpoint in Rails using Mongodb

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongodb

I am attempting to build a Rails backend using Mongodb that is just an API application. I have an events model and api controller and when I go to localhost:3000/events/2, I am getting a 404 error, although I know the record is in my database:

```
{ "_id" : 2, "name" : "String Cheese", "location" : "Durham, NC", "price" : "40.00" }
```

My controller looks like this:

```
class API::V1::EventsController < ApplicationController
  respond_to :json

  def show
    respond_with Event.find('_id')
  end

  private

  def event_params
    params.require(:event).permit(:name, :url, :location, :dates, :price, :info, :genre, :address, :city, :tags)
  end
end
```

And my routes look like this:

```
require 'api_constraints'

Rails.application.routes.draw do

  namespace :api, defaults: { format: :json }, path: '/' do
    scope module: :v1, constraints: ApiConstraints.new(version: 1, default: true) do
      resources :users, only: [:show]
      resources :events, only: [:show]
    end
  end
end
```

And then I have an api_constraints.rb in my lib folder that looks like this:

```
class ApiConstraints
  def initialize(options)
    @version = options[:version]
    @default = options[:default]
  end

  def matches?(req)
    @default || req.headers['Accept'].include?("application/vnd.marketplace.v#{@version}")
  end
end
```

This is to remove the need for having the api version number in the uri. I'm not sure if it is effecting my endpoint.

So then when I start my server and go to `localhost:3000/events/2` I get a 404 error:

{"status":404,"error":"Not Found","exception":"#\u003cMongoid::Errors::DocumentNotFound: \nmessage:\n  Document(s) not found for class Event with id(s) {\"_id\"=\u003e\"2\"}.\nsummary:\n  When calling Event.find with an id or array of ids, each parameter must match a document in the database or this error will be raised. The search was for the id(s): {\"_id\"=\u003e\"2\"}

The stack trace is actually even longer, so i can post the whole thing if anyone needs it.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My apologies, it turns out the reason was I had incorrectly stored a new record in mongo through my terminal. I incorrectly wrote a new entry using this:

`db.events.insert( { "_id" : 2, "name" : "Phish" } )`

and I should have done it like this:

`db.events.insert( { _id: '2', name: "Phish" } )`

I am still not very familiar with Mongodb, but it appears they save all IDs as strings and I had an ID saved as an integer, which it then could not find.

Comment: Mongoid stores IDs as `BSON::ObjectId` by default - not strings. https://docs.mongodb.com/ruby-driver/master/tutorials/6.0.0/mongoid-documents/

Answer (score 1):

`Event.find('_id')` will look for a record with `_id = "_id"`.

You need to use the id parameter from the URL.

```
Event.find(params[:id])
```

Comment: When I changed it to that, I still got a 404 error:

Started GET "/events/2" for ::1 at 2017-01-03 10:32:00 -0500
Processing by Api::V1::EventsController#show as JSON
   Parameters: {"id"=>"2"}
MONGODB | localhost:27017 | go_loco_development.find | STARTED | {"find"=>"events", "filter"=>{"_id"=>"2"}}
MONGODB | localhost:27017 | go_loco_development.find | SUCCEEDED | 0.000573s
Completed 404 Not Found in 2ms

Comment: @Lukas Try converting it to Fixnum - the document you've included in the question has id which is an integer, not a string: `{ "_id" : 2 .....`. So something like `Event.find(params[:id].to_i)`.

Comment: I would avoid manually creating IDs altogether. Go with the default scheme of `BSON::ObjectId`. While it may seem ugly compared to simple numerical ids it does solve a very real problem when it comes to replicated databases where auto-incrementing columns are subject to race conditions.